SoapClient - Problem with changing location
I have several locations from the creator of the application for one WebAPI, such as http://www.someadres/backend.php/webapi/soap?wsdl, http://www.someadres/backend.php/user/soap?wsdl
The first one concerns logging in and receiving an idSession, which is needed to perform the available functions.
Performs the following actions
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.someadres/backend.php/webapi/soap?wsdl", array('login' => "someLogin", 'password' => somePassword"));

$idSession=$client->doLogin($UserSote); //UserSote is an object passed as an argument to the function

/* I get the session id*/
/* Now I'm trying to change the location because the necessary functions are available in the second location provided by the application creator */

$client->__setLocation('http://www.someadres/backend.php/user/soap?wsdl');

$UserTab=$client->GetUserList($UserListOpt);


Unfortunately, I receive a message saying that the GetUserList function does not exist. I checked using __getFunctions() and got the set of functions that is at the first location. It appears that the location has not been changed. Why?
I tried calling again
$client->__soapCall('GetUserList',['_session_hash'=>serialize($idSession),'_offset'=>'0','_limit'=>'100'], ['location' => "http: //someaddress/backend.php/user/soap?wsdl"]);


This did not bring any results.
Please give me tips to solve this problem
